# Obtaining column shares of top 5 values across columns

Tags: r

I have the following data stored in a list:

```
set.seed = 12345
df1 = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:500,1000,rep=TRUE)))
df2 = data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:500,1000,rep=TRUE)))
list = list(df1, df2)
```

How can I do the following:

1) For each column, obtain the share of each element in the column sum (i.e., each element divided by the column total)
2) For each column, take the sum of these shares for the *top 5 values only* (where the order of these top 5 values will be different across columns)

The output, then, would be a list of 2 vectors (one for each of df1 and df2) containing 10 shares each.

I'd like to use the apply family to accomplish this. Any advice, however, would be welcome. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop over the `list` with `lapply`, divide the dataset by the column sums of each column ('x1'), select the top 5 by looping (`sapply`) through each column, `sort` it, and get the `head`, and then `cbind` the `list` elements to create a dataset of two columns

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(list, function(x) {
   x1 <- x/colSums(x)[col(x)]
   sapply(x1, function(y) sum(head(sort(y, decreasing = TRUE), 5)))}))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(list, ~ .x %>% 
               summarise_all(funs(sum(tail(sort(./sum(.)), 5)))) %>% 
               unlist %>%
               as_tibble) %>%
   bind_cols
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. On your first suggestion, what does [col(x)] do?

Comment: @nymuffin  It is just to make the lengths same by replicating before we do `/`

Comment: Thank @akrun. So just to be super clear, what would happen to column 1 of df1 if we didn't include [col(x)]? I'm looking at the results after removing [col(x)], not clear what this is telling me

Comment: @nymuffin  What will happen is that it divide the first element of column 1 by the first colSums, then 2nd element of column1 by the second colSums, instead of dividing the whole column 1, by the whole colSums of the first column

Comment: Thanks so much, you're awesome

Comment: @nymuffin  Consider this simple example `m1 <- matrix(1:16, 4, 4);  m1/colSums(m1);  m1/colSums(m1)[col(m1)]`